# How to convert list of type str to int using while loop , without built-in functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very new in Programming and i am trying to convert this list of type string into type integer . but when i am checking the type after conversion it is the same.

```
def strList(lis):
    length=len(lis)
    j=0
    while (j<length):
        lis[j] = int(lis[j])   
        j+=1
    return lis
lis=['1','1','2','3']
print lis
print type(lis)
lis2=strList(lis)
```

output :

['1', '1', '2', '3']

type 'list'

type 'list'

Comment: your code works, try `print lis2`

Comment: for better solution read about list comprehensions in Python: `lis2 = [int(s) for s in lis]`

Comment: They are not using built-in functions. No `int`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use List Comprehension, if you want to convert a list of strings to a list of ints -

```
def strList(lis):
    return [int(i) for i in lis]

print(strList(['1','1','2','3']))
```

Output: `[1, 1, 2, 3]`